# Converting a text file into table using R

Tags: r, database

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d6LoHL9ysECMjOrhEtfo-uSl-m4DlnJD/view

The text file is in the link which needs to be converted into a table using R.

When I try doing it with read.text and read.table it gives me an error of:
"Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :"

Also, not able to parse the text file so that I can debug the error.

Any help would be appericiated. Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to provide a reproducible example to help others to answer your question. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) post. [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) package is also a good way to start.

Comment: Have you looked at the file? It has no semblance whatsoever of a tabular format, it's JSON. I did a cursory scan of it, and it isn't going to be as simple as "make this a table", with multiple elements with varying depths and such. While there is certainly some consistency to some of its sections, I think you're going to be hard-pressed to ask for charity work to figure all of that out for you, especially given the dearth of context given here (and effort shown). Look into the `jsonlite` package.